# ngFor call function Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

The following works:

```
*ngFor="let child of items || []; let i = index;"
```

This doesn't:

```
*ngFor="let child of items || []; let specialVersionOfI = someFunction(index);"
```

I get:

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token (, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 56 in [ngFor let child of items |
```

What's the reasoning behind this, and is there an alterantive?

Comment: I guess `items || []` is might be confusing parser, change it to `(items || [])` wrap with a bracket

Comment: I still get the same issue without it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the function later within the loop, not when you assign the index.

```
<u>
   <li *ngFor="let item of items || []; let i=index">
      use function here >> {{someFunction(i)}}
   </li>
</u>
```

You could also manipulate the array in the model and store the special index in a second parallel array, then access it within the template.

```
<u>
   <li *ngFor="let item of items || []; let i=index">
      access special index >> {{customIndices[i]}}
   </li>
</u>
```

Comment: Agree with this answer. The way `*ngFor` work is that it's a sugar syntax over some other bindings. When the Angular compile runs, it is compiled into multiple bindings. The syntax of ngFor is not well documented (at least I couldn't find a comprehensive guideline on how the parsing work currently), so it's better to leave it as simple as possible and add your custom logic inside the loop as @BeetleJuice suggested

Answer (score 1):

Much more readable will be version with mapping in component, sth like:

`this.items.map((child, i) => { 
  child['specialVersionOfI'] = this.someFunction(i); 
  return child;
})`
and then in template just `{{child.specialVersionOfI}}`

Comment: Well, these two are the obvious workarounds, in fact this is what I'm using right now... but they are still workarounds. I'm wondering if they plan on implementing this anytime soon?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't say it's workaround. In my opinion it is better to keep view only responsible for showing data instead of making decision which and where make some calculation.

Comment: A big reason to want it is when the special computed value is needed in multiple places and so you want to only calculate it once for each loop iteration rather than over and over via individual function calls (or having to gum up the logic trying to do some sort of value caching inside the function).